# How to add a value and onclick handler to emberjs template for AnchorTag

Tags: ember.js

I have the following in my template

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{view ChatApp.SomeAnchor}}
</script>
```

I have this defined as a custom view in my ember code

```
ChatApp.SomeAnchor = Ember.View.extend({
  tagName: 'a',
  attributeBindings: ['href'],
  href: '#'                                                                                                                                                                       
});
```

The html generated looks like this

```
<a id="ember211" class="ember-view" href="#"></a>
```

My question is -how can I modify the ember object to provide a custom onclick and value so it looks like this

```
<a id="ember211" onclick="something(); return false;" class="ember-view" href="#">Click This</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you explain why you would want inline javascript in your HTML?

If you want to just override the click behavior on your view, simply add a click handler:

```
ChatApp.SomeAnchor = Ember.View.extend({
  tagName: 'a',
  attributeBindings: ['href'],
  href: '#',
  click:function(){
    //do your thing here.
    return false;
  }                                                                                                                                                                      
});
```

Comment: To be clear - the click event would simply invoke a controller action (doesn't need to be literal "onclick")

Comment: @ToranBillups so, aren't you looking for the {{action}} helper ? http://emberjs.com/documentation/#toc_handling-events-with-action

Comment: nice -action help was exactly what I needed!

Comment: @sly7_7 You should change this comment as an answer, as it is the correct one.